# MySQL - Joining two tables with datetime columns on Date and three most recent entries before that date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, group-by

I have two tables in my SQL

For example **Table1 - ItemPrice**:

```
DATETIME   |  ITEM | PRICE
2011-08-28 |   ABC   123 
2011-09-01 |   ABC   125
2011-09-02 |   ABC   124 
2011-09-03 |   ABC   127 
2011-09-04 |   ABC   126
```

**Table2 - DayScore**:

```
DATETIME   |  ITEM | SCORE
2011-08-28 |   ABC    1
2011-08-29 |   ABC    8
2011-09-01 |   ABC    4
2011-09-02 |   ABC    2
2011-09-03 |   ABC    7  
2011-09-04 |   ABC    3
```

I want to write a query, which given a item ID (e.g. *ABC*), will return the price at that date from `ItemPrice` (of there is no price for that date then the query should not return anything). If a valid price is found for the query date, the query should return (in 9 columns)

- the price of the item from `ItemPrice` for the past three days (i.e. the most recent 3 prices before the date queried).
- In the next three columns it should return, from `DayScore`, the matching score for those 3 dates selected from ItemPrice.
- Finally the dates (t-1 to t-3) selected

In otherwords the results for this query looking at just date='2011-09-03' as an example for item='abc' would return:

```
DATE      |  ITEM  |  PRICE  |  SCR  | PRC_t-1 | PRC_t-2 | PRC_t-3 | SCR_t-1 | SCR_t-2 | SCR_t-3 | DATE_t-1  | DATE_t-2  | DATE_t-3 
2011-09-03|  ABC   |  127    |  7    | 124     | 125     | 123     | 2       | 4       | 1       | 2011-09-02| 2011-09-01| 2011-08-28
....
```

Etc for each date that appears in `ItemPrice` table.

What is the neatest and most efficient way to run this query (as its something that will be run over many millions of rows)?

Cheers!

Comment: what did you try so far? let's start from your current situation and not from scratch :)

Comment: I would, but what I have thus far, it's embarrassing, and decided not to post, so scratch is pretty much where I'm at... But in a nutshell multiple selects...

Comment: Although this is an interesting challenge that depending on how you define 'neat' could be really neat but I doubt it can be done efficiently. I expect that the fastest way is to simply get all the rows for ABC as straight rows (item, price, score) and build your structure on the client using whatever programming language you have there.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a price for each calendar day.  In other words it looks like your price table only contains rows for days on which the item price changed.  Is that correct?  That puts you into an intricate self-join situation.  For efficiency's sake, can you define a time horizon?  Can you say there's no need to look, let's say, more than seven days back to get the most recent price changes?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. At this stage we are really defining neat as understandable & efficient as a working proc. @Eddy - yes this is a very good idea and have built wrapper views which basically give what I have in the above example.

With the calendar days, we could limit it (not ideal), the prices are basically listed there for whatever value the price was on a trading day (i.e. no prices on public holidays or weekends). But there may be other cases where the item was not trading, a 10 day period would be better but if you have an idea with the 7 day limitation we would be interested!

Comment: With the idea of the client side solution, this is something we have considered. Being Java we shouldn't have issues with the set, but we really want to run this as a batch process every week, given the volume of records we are looking at, the client side solution becomes more frustrating, managing the volumes of data, tweaking caching, and risking many thousands of calls to the database, network OH, etc is something we were hoping to avoid and keep this logic at the data later inside the DB. Mutliple selects, temp tables and the like would be better (IMO) than having to port the data to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty no but it does produce the results. You could probably get rid of some subselects and make it a bit less sql but I tried to build it up in steps so you can deduct what it is doing.

The core part is this select:

```
SELECT 
  Sub2.*
, (Select MAX(IP3.DateTime) FROM ItemPrice IP3 where IP3.DateTime < T_2) AS T_3
FROM
   (SELECT 
        Sub1.*
      , (Select MAX(IP2.DateTime) FROM ItemPrice IP2 where IP2.DateTime < T_1) AS T_2
    FROM
       (SELECT 
            ItemPrice.DateTime
          , (Select MAX(IP.DateTime) FROM ItemPrice IP where IP.DateTime < ItemPrice.DateTime) AS T_1 
        From ItemPrice) Sub1
   ) Sub2
```

This returns a table with the dates (now, t-1, t-2, t-3). From there is is simple joining with price and score for each of those dates. The whole things including testdata the becomes this bulk of sql

```
/*
CREATE TABLE ItemPrice (datetime Date, item varchar(3), price int);
CREATE TABLE DayScore ( datetime Date, item varchar(3), score int);

INSERT INTO ItemPrice VALUES ('20110828', 'ABC', 123);
INSERT INTO ItemPrice VALUES ('20110901', 'ABC', 125);
INSERT INTO ItemPrice VALUES ('20110902', 'ABC', 124);
INSERT INTO ItemPrice VALUES ('20110903', 'ABC', 127);
INSERT INTO ItemPrice VALUES ('20110904', 'ABC', 126);

INSERT INTO DayScore VALUES ('20110828', 'ABC', 1);
INSERT INTO DayScore VALUES ('20110829', 'ABC', 8);
INSERT INTO DayScore VALUES ('20110901', 'ABC', 4);
INSERT INTO DayScore VALUES ('20110902', 'ABC', 2);
INSERT INTO DayScore VALUES ('20110903', 'ABC', 7);
INSERT INTO DayScore VALUES ('20110904', 'ABC', 3);
*/

SELECT Hist.*, Current.Item, Current.Price, Current.Score
, Minus1.Price as PRC_1, Minus1.Score SCR_1
, Minus2.Price as PRC_2, Minus2.Score SCR_2
, Minus3.Price as PRC_3, Minus3.Score SCR_3
FROM 
    (SELECT Sub2.*, (Select MAX(IP3.DateTime) FROM ItemPrice IP3 where IP3.DateTime < T_2) AS T_3
    FROM
        (SELECT Sub1.*, (Select MAX(IP2.DateTime) FROM ItemPrice IP2 where IP2.DateTime < T_1) AS T_2
        FROM
            (SELECT ItemPrice.DateTime, (Select MAX(IP.DateTime) FROM ItemPrice IP where IP.DateTime < ItemPrice.DateTime) AS T_1 From ItemPrice) Sub1) Sub2) Hist 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ItemPrice.DateTime, ItemPrice.Item, ItemPrice.Price, DayScore.Score FROM ItemPrice INNER JOIN DayScore ON (ItemPrice.Item = DayScore.Item AND ItemPrice.Datetime = DayScore.DateTime)) CURRENT
ON (Current.DateTime = Hist.DateTime)        
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ItemPrice.DateTime, ItemPrice.Price, DayScore.Score FROM ItemPrice INNER JOIN DayScore ON (ItemPrice.Item = DayScore.Item AND ItemPrice.Datetime = DayScore.DateTime)) MINUS1
ON (Minus1.DateTime = Hist.T_1)        
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ItemPrice.DateTime, ItemPrice.Price, DayScore.Score FROM ItemPrice INNER JOIN DayScore ON (ItemPrice.Item = DayScore.Item AND ItemPrice.Datetime = DayScore.DateTime)) MINUS2
ON (Minus2.DateTime = Hist.T_2)        
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ItemPrice.DateTime, ItemPrice.Price, DayScore.Score FROM ItemPrice INNER JOIN DayScore ON (ItemPrice.Item = DayScore.Item AND ItemPrice.Datetime = DayScore.DateTime)) MINUS3
ON (Minus3.DateTime = Hist.T_3)        
WHERE Current.Item = 'ABC'

;

/*
DROP TABLE ItemPrice;
DROP TABLE DayScore;
*/
```

I'm curious about your explain plan when you do this on 1M rows :) It might not even be that horrible if you have the right indexes which you probably do.

Comment: Eddy, you sir are a genius! Thank you so much for your answer! Just ran this one against the prod dataset (2.6M item prices and 600k scores), takes about a 2.5 mins to run. Returns all the results expected! Legend!